# How should we prove that two circles can intersect at two points( at least)?

Tags: circles

Assume that there are two distinct circles with centres C and D respectively.
I feel that these two circles can intersect at two points but I don't know **how to prove that they can intersect at two points**!
However I tried to prove it by construction like this- "I firstly construct a circle and then I again construct other circle with a compass such that they both intersect each other at two points."
Is my way of proving correct?
If not,then please provide an appropriate proof for this?
THANKS!
[image]

Comment: It depends on the distance between 2 centres. For instance, if the distance between centres is the sum of the radii of both circles, then they touch at 1 point only.

Comment: Do you want an algebraic proof or a compass and straight-edge proof?

Comment: @B.Goddard compass and straight-edge proof

Comment: Two points *at most*. You can have two circles that are completely disjoint, or two circles that are tangent (and intersect at only one point).

Answer (score 2):

The key point to a proof is that if you have three non-collinear points, they determine a *unique* circle. (So two distinct circles can intersect in at most two points.) You can prove this by construction: The center of the circle will be the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the segments joining pairs of the points.

Answer (score 1):

Of course,
there's the analytic approach.

Moving one of the circles to the origin,
the equations are

$x^2+y^2 = r^2$
and
$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = s^2$.

Subtracting the second from the first,

$2ax-a^2+2by-b^2 = r^2-s^2$
or
$2ax+2by 
= r^2-s^2+a^2+b^2
=c$.

If $b=0$,
then
$a \ne 0$
(or else the two circles 
are concentric
and then have zero or
an infinite number of intersections)
so that
$x = c/2$
and
$y^2
=r^2-x^2
=r^2-\frac{c^2}{4}
$
which has zero,
one, or two solutions depending on
the sign of
$4r^2-c^2$.

If $b\ne 0$,
then
$y = \frac{c}{2b}-\frac{ax}{b}$.
putting this in the first equation,

$\begin{array}\\
r^2
&=x^2+\left(\frac{c}{2b}-\frac{ax}{b}\right)^2\\
&=x^2+\frac{c^2}{4b^2}-\frac{acx}{b^2}+\frac{a^2x^2}{b^2}\\
&=x^2\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2}-x\frac{ac}{b^2}+\frac{c^2}{4b^2}\\
\text{or}\\
0
&=x^2\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2}-x\frac{ac}{b^2}+\frac{c^2}{4b^2}-r^2\\
&=x^2\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2}-x\frac{ac}{b^2}+\frac{c^2-4b^2r^2}{4b^2}\\
\end{array}
$

This is a quadratic in $x$
and so has
zero, one, or two real roots
depending on the sign
of the discriminant which is

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{a^2c^2}{b^4}-\frac{(a^2+b^2)(c^2-4b^2r^2)}{b^4}
&=\frac{a^2c^2-(a^2+b^2)c^2+4b^2r^2(a^2+b^2)}{b^4}\\
&=\frac{b^2(4r^2(a^2+b^2)-c^2)}{b^4}\\
&=\frac{4r^2(a^2+b^2)-c^2}{b^2}\\
\end{array}
$

You can substitute 
the actual expression for $c$
to get results involving
only $a, b, r,$
and $s$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would draw the line through $C$ and $D$.  Then draw the circle centered at $D$, or at least an arc of it that cuts the segment $CD$ at $P$.  Set the compass for the radius of the circle centered at $C$, but draw the circle of that radius centered at $P$.  If $C$ is inside that circle, then there are two intersection points.